# Node wait for async function before continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have a node application that use some async functions.

How can i do for waiting the asynchronous function to complete before proceeding with the rest of the application flow?

Below there is a simple example.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
a = a + b;

// this async function requires at least 30 sec
myAsyncFunction({}, function(data, err) {
    a = 5;
});

// TODO wait for async function

console.log(a); // it must be 5 and not 1
return a;
```

In the example, the element "`a`" to return must be 5 and not 1. It is equal to 1 if the application does not wait the async function.

Thanks

Comment: Great and useful comment

Comment: Yes, promises and `async`/`await` syntax sugar - as you suggested in the tags - are the way to go. Have you tried applying them to your problem? Please show your efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Using callback mechanism:

```
function operation(callback) {

    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    a = a + b;
    a = 5;

    // may be a heavy db call or http request?
    // do not return any data, use callback mechanism
    callback(a)
}

operation(function(a /* a is passed using callback */) {
    console.log(a); // a is 5
})
```

### Using async await

```
async function operation() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var a = 0;
        var b = 1;
        a = a + b;
        a = 5;

        // may be a heavy db call or http request?
        resolve(a) // successfully fill promise
    })
}

async function app() {
    var a = await operation() // a is 5
}

app()
```

Comment: I have been searching for a good explanation of Promise and finally found one! Thank you!

Comment: None of the two alternatives actually waits. In particular `a` returned by `await` is not 5. Instead it is a promise, which is just another way to require a callback. The right answer would be: you can not wait.

Comment: operation function doesn't need to have async before it, since its not using await. Its redundant since async makes it so that the function returns a promise, but operation() already is returning a promise.