# How to ensure async function returns value before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have looked at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158979/node-wait-for-async-function-before-continue) but can't get it to work for my needs.

I have an `async` function in an `offer.js` file, which I need to call from a Controller file. The `offer.js` file works correctly and returns JSON data. It's the calling Controller file which I can't get to 'wait' for the data to come back before continuing with the rest of the page.

This is what the Controller file does:

```
var router = require('express').Router(); // Express.js router functionality
const Offer = require('../models/offer'); // the offer.js file which has getAllOffers() async function

// call/return the data from getAllOffers() async function
var rsOffersAll = async function() {
  return await Offer.getAllOffers(); 
}

// I would like rsOffersAll to have data before doing anything further at this point.

// if the homepage, supply the rsOffersAll data to the view.
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { data: rsOffersAll  });  // the data needs to be here. this should not run until the data is available to pass to the view
});
```

How do I ensure that `var rsOffersAll` has data before the `router.get...` stuff executes?

Comment: `router.get('/',` **async** `function(...) { ... { data:` **await** `rsOffersAll` **()**  }); ...});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsOffersAll` is redundant here, you `await` the result internally but you don't then `await` the result of `rsOffersAll` from the route handler.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await Offers.getAllOffers();
  res.render('index', { data });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this. but what if I want to do this `res.render('index', { pagetitle: 'Homepage', metadesc: 'The site's homepage',  data: rsOffersAll  });` where I want to pass more parameters to the view than just the `data` ?

Comment: @volumeone just add them: `{ pagetitle: 'Homepage', /* ... */, data }` (but just keep `data`, don't do `data: rsOffersAll`) Just having `data` is equivalent to having `data: data`.

Comment: @volumeone as blex has already explained, I've simply made use of [short-hand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), if you need more properties then you simply add them like you would normally

Comment: if I do this `router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await Offers.getAllOffers();
console.dir(data);
  res.render('index', { data });
});` How come `data` never prints to the console?

Comment: `console.dir` prints an object properties, presumable `data` is an array? Try just `console.log`

Comment: If I run `(async function () {
  var data = await Offer.getAllOffers();
  console.dir(data);
})();` then I get the `data` in the console fine as a JSON string. When I run it in the router like in your answer, it hangs for ages and then I get an error saying "Database is already connected! Call close before connecting to different database." Should I ask a new question about this?

Comment: @volumeone yes, you would appear to be opening a global connection and not closing therefore when another request comes in it hangs

Comment: I have closed the connection properly and that error has gone away. But the code still won't run when I place it inside the `router.get()`. I now get an login failure with my database, but I get no such failure if do `(async function () { var data = await Offer.getAllOffers(); console.dir(data); })();` outside of `router.get()`. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: @volumeone sorry these questions are way off-topic now, and clearly related to your DB setup. I would advise you open up a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

> `rsOffersAll` is `async`  and it will return a promise so you can use
>   then

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    rsOffersAll().then((res) = >{
        res.render('index', { data: res  });
    });

});
```

Comment: I wouldnt recommend mixing Promises & async / await

Comment: @James can you explain the little bit reason for this ?

Comment: are you saying you agree with me but don't understand why? 