# Await for function before end()

Tags: node.js

**edit:** added a bit more code.

```
    const express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();

    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})

    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
    const iot = require('@google-cloud/iot');
    const API_VERSION = 'v1';

    const DISCOVERY_API = 'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest';
    app.get('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {

    const projectId = req.query.proyecto;
    const cloudRegion = req.query.region;
    const registryId = req.query.registro;
    const numSerie = req.query.numSerie;
    const command = req.query.command;

    const client = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient();
    if (client === undefined) {
        console.log('Did not instantiate client.');
    } else {
        console.log('Did instantiate client.');
        sendCom();
    }

    async function sendCom() {
        const formattedName = await client.devicePath(projectId, cloudRegion, registryId, numSerie)
        const binaryData = Buffer.from(command);
        const request = {
            name: formattedName,
            binaryData: binaryData,
        };
        return client.sendCommandToDevice(request).then(responses => res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
            data: OK
        }))).catch(err => res.status(404).send('Could not send command. Is the device connected?'));
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have this function, that I call after the *client* initiate:  *sendCom();*

```
     async function sendCom() {
        const formattedName = await client.devicePath(projectId, cloudRegion, registryId, deviceId)
        const binaryData = Buffer.from(command);            
        const request = { name: formattedName, binaryData: binaryData, };

        client.sendCommandToDevice(request)
        .then(responses => {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ data: OK })).end();                
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(404).send('Could not send command. Is the device connected?').end();             
        });
    }
```

My problem is that **sendCommandToDevice** gets executed perfectly, however I get the **catch** **error**.
As I understand it, it's because in the **.then** ends the connection.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158979/node-wait-for-async-function-before-continue) and thats's what I tried, however I'm not sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: you are using `res.status....` while your lambda get `responses`. where is `res` come from?

Comment: @OmriAttiya its in app.get('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {} All the code I posted above is here.

Comment: @Farrukh Yeah, as I said I think that's the problem. But I'm not sure where or how should I .end() it?

Comment: Well for this case you don't need to call .end() because there is no buffer you are making to send the response plus @OmriAttiya is right about res.status it should be responses.status...

Comment: @Farrukh I've updated the post with a more comprehesive code, if that helps. I've changed to what you and OmriAttiya said. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `send` with `end`.

- `end()` is used when you want to end the request and want to respond with no data.
- `send()` is used to end the request and respond with some data.

You can found more about it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).

Comment: Thanks. I removed the .end() However I face the same problem. Even if the try is succesful and the sendCommandToDevice works, I still get as repsonse the catch.